# Asignarle valor por defecto a EditorFor, con fecha actual del equipo

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Rescatar la fecha con DateTime.Today u otra cosa y asignársela al EditorFor, ya que la fecha es un string.

```
  <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha)
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al usar `EditorFor` estas diciendo que el campo de tipo fecha hereda de un tipo de plantilla que has definido en `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`, por lo que tienes dos opciones:

1. Creas una plantilla en `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Date.cshtml` ó `Datetime.cshtml` depende del tipo que le diste en tu modelo con algo similar a esto:

   ```
   @inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime?>

   @if (Model.HasValue)
   {
       @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model.Value), new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
   }
   else
   {
       @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now), new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
   }
   ```

   De esta forma estás declarando que todos tus inputs de tipo Date tomarán ese estilo siempre y cuando lo llames con el helper `EditorFor`
2. Pasarlo directo en ese campo con el helper `TextBox`

   ```
   @Html.TextBox("Fecha", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

yo lo haria de la manera mas sencilla, cuando el modelo esta vacio, tomaria el dato normal por medio del mismo modelo y cuando vayas a mostrar el valor, es decir que sea un dato que ya guardaste en db y quieras verlo a manera de informacion si lo pasas como string, seria algo asi para que se entienda mejor:

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha,htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @if(model.modelId > 0)
        {
             <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" value="@ViewBag.fecha"/>
                   <div>
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span> 
                   </div>
             </div>
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha)
        }
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha)
    </div>
</div>
```

Y en el controlador obtienes el dato del modelo en un ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.fecha = model.fecha.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Espero haber entendido bien y que te sirva la idea para solucionar hermano.